# Giving a variable two values if no row exists in the database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table called `user_bio`, which has the following columns:

```
   id
   age
   studying
   relationship_status
   username
   about_me
```

Currently, this table has one row for user `conor`:

```
   id; 1
   age: 30
   studying: test
   relationship_status: single
   username: conor
   about_me: test
```

If I log in as `Conor` and go to `bio.php/conor`, the bio for conor will display fine. But, if I log in as `Alice` and go to `bio.php/alice`, I get undefined variable errors except for age, which shows correctly (with the correct value for each user).

Here is my code, and how I am displaying the data:

```
<?php
/****************************************/
// Getting data to display on bio page for user
$get_bio = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM user_bio WHERE username ='$user'");
$row_returned = mysqli_num_rows($get_bio);
if ($row_returned == 1){
    while ($get_bio_data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_bio)){
        $about_me = $get_bio_data['about_me'];
        $age = $get_bio_data['age'];
        $studying = $get_bio_data['studying'];
        $lang = $get_bio_data['language'];
        $rel_status = $get_bio_data['relationship_status'];
        /*****************************************/
        // change data held by vars 
        // if no bio for the user exists in the db (no rows in db)s
        if ($row_returned == 0){
            if ($about_me == ""){
                $about_me = "None set..";
            } else {
                $about_me = $get_bio_data['about_me'];
            } // else closed
        } // if closed
    } // while closed
} // if closed
/*********************************************/
?>
<div id="userposts_panel">
    <div class="bio_here">
        <p> <b> About me: </b>  <?php echo $about_me; ?> </p>
        <p> <b> Age: </b>  <?php echo $age; ?> </p>
        <p> <b> Studying: </b>  <?php echo $studying; ?> </p>
        <p> <b> Language(s): </b>  <?php echo $lang; ?> </p>
        <p> <b> Relationship Status: </b>  <?php echo $rel_status; ?> </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I think because there is no row in the database corresponding to `username` alice, this is causing the error. In which case I want to redefine the variable my selected string, for example, if `about_me` exists for the user, then display it, else $about_me will equal `none set`. But I am still getting undefined errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just not enter into `if ($row_returned == 1){` if there are no user Alice. So you need to initialize variables ($about_me, $age, ...) before this if.

Try this code:

```
<?php
/****************************************/

// change data held by vars if no bio for the user exists in the db (no rows in db)s
$about_me = "None set..";
$age = "None set..";
$studying = "None set..";
$lang = "None set..";
$rel_status = "None set..";

// Getting data to display on bio page for user
$get_bio = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM user_bio WHERE username ='$user'");
$row_returned = mysqli_num_rows($get_bio);
if ($row_returned == 1){
    while ($get_bio_data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_bio)){
        $about_me = $get_bio_data['about_me'];
        $age = $get_bio_data['age'];
        $studying = $get_bio_data['studying'];
        $lang = $get_bio_data['language'];
        $rel_status = $get_bio_data['relationship_status'];
        /*****************************************/
    } // while closed
} // if closed
/*********************************************/
?>
<div id="userposts_panel">
    <div class="bio_here">
        <p> <b> About me: </b>  <?php echo $about_me; ?> </p>
        <p> <b> Age: </b>  <?php echo $age; ?> </p>
        <p> <b> Studying: </b>  <?php echo $studying; ?> </p>
        <p> <b> Language(s): </b>  <?php echo $lang; ?> </p>
        <p> <b> Relationship Status: </b>  <?php echo $rel_status; ?> </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) method to check if variable is set or not as below :

```
<div id="userposts_panel">
                    <div class="bio_here">
                            <p> <b> About me: </b>  <?php if(isset($about_me)){ echo $about_me;} else{ echo "none";} ?> </p>
                            <p> <b> Age: </b>  <?php if(isset($age)){ echo $age;} else{echo "none";} ?> </p>
                            <p> <b> Studying: </b>  <?php if(isset($studying)){ echo $studying;} else{ echo "none";} ?> </p>
                            <p> <b> Language(s): </b>  <?php if(isset($lang)){ echo $lang;} else { echo "none";} ?> </p>
                            <p> <b> Relationship Status: </b>  <?php if(isset($rel_stautus)){ echo $rel_status;} else{ echo "none";} ?> </p>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
/****************************************/
// Getting data to display on bio page for user
$get_bio = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM user_bio WHERE username ='$user'");
$row_returned = mysqli_num_rows($get_bio);
if ($row_returned == 1){
    while ($get_bio_data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_bio)){
        $about_me = $get_bio_data['about_me'];
        $age = $get_bio_data['age'];
        $studying = $get_bio_data['studying'];
        $lang = $get_bio_data['language'];
        $rel_status = $get_bio_data['relationship_status'];
    } // while closed
} // if closed
else {
    $about_me = "Not set...";
    $age = "Not set...";
    $studying = "Not set...";
    $lang = "Not set...";
    $rel_status = "Not set...";
} // else closed
/*********************************************/
?>
<div id="userposts_panel">
    <div class="bio_here">
        <p> <b> About me: </b>  <?php echo $about_me; ?> </p>
        <p> <b> Age: </b>  <?php echo $age; ?> </p>
        <p> <b> Studying: </b>  <?php echo $studying; ?> </p>
        <p> <b> Language(s): </b>  <?php echo $lang; ?> </p>
        <p> <b> Relationship Status: </b>  <?php echo $rel_status; ?> </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
function checkValue($getValue) {
   return isset($getValue) ? $getValue : "N/A";
}
?>

<div id="userposts_panel">
    <div class="bio_here">
        <p> <b> About me: </b>  <?php echo checkValue(&$about_me); ?> </p>
        <p> <b> Age: </b>  <?php echo checkValue(&$age); ?> </p>
        <p> <b> Studying: </b>  <?php echo checkValue(&$studying); ?> </p>
        <p> <b> Language(s): </b>  <?php echo checkValue(&$lang); ?> </p>
        <p> <b> Relationship Status: </b>  <?php echo checkValue(&$rel_status); ?> </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

you could use `&` as an ignorant and use a function to check, whether the value is set and if not set display some required Text.